# Schengen Business Visa after a name change

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

I am a citizen of India and working in a well known company in Bangalore. I have to apply for a Schengen Business Visa for 3 months.
Recently I have changed my legal name but not yet updated my passport with the new name. 
Can I apply for a Schengen Visa with the old name itself, if it matches with the name in my passport?
Or will it violate any rule or is it a crime to do so?

Please help me to do the next steps.

Comment: Perhaps your first step should be to get a new passport, one that bears your correct legal name.

Answer (score 1):

The name in your visa should match the name in the passport you will carry on your travels. The instructions which accompany Schengen visa applications, this [example for France](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/download-schengen-visa-application-form/france/), directs you on how to fill in each section (emphasis mine):

> 1. Surname: type your last name **as it appears on your passport**
> 2. Surname at birth: type your last name at birth (even if it’s the same as item #1)
> 3. First names: type out your first and middle names **as they appear on your passport**