# German Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas, passport-renewals

I have a valid German Schengen visa which I got on my old passport. I applied for a new passport , when was issued, my name was changed slightly. My old passport had both my surname and given name (vijay kumar) in the given name column with the surname column blank but now my new passport shows my given name (vijay) and surname (kumar) separately (and correctly). can i travel with same visa ?

Comment: In general, major changes to your personal details (ie. name changes) require you to apply for a new visa. If I were you, I would apply for a new visa as there is no reason not to... 

Check out the reply in this thread, it's for a business visa but it may help.
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92238/schengen-business-visa-after-a-name-change

Answer (score 1):

As i understand, in first passport you left your last name blank but in second passport you filled it with kumar.
Please get in touch with German embassy and get this clarified.
In my view, itshould be fine but It depends on how Immigration officer interprets it.

Comment: Thanks for information. i dont have enough time to apply for a visa.

Comment: Well you taking a risk. Although chances are that it will be fine but still you should have got it confirmed in time